# VBA Macro to identify if Filter criteria on a excel Table shows data or not and if it does, how to get the specific Colum cell filtered data

Tags: vba

I'm trying to work a excel table than contains more than 300000 records, I need to apply a filter based on #N/A criteria on one column and then get those records (only the data of two columns) and used to create a vlook up to extract some information on another table. Filter result is no more than 5 records

Comment: I don't see any question here, only some vague requirements

Comment: The typical way to get visible rows after filtering is to use `yourTableRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`  Plenty of examples here on SO if you search for that.